# How to get a second header in pandas-Dataframe that was built from a list using zip()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting from the code below I want to expand my code.

```py
import pandas as pd

df_area = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["area1", "area2","area1"],
                        "B": [2, 5,7],
                        "C": ["BUS_X","BUS_Y","BUS_Y"]})
df_time = pd.DataFrame({"area1": [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000],
                        "area2": [2000, 5000, 6000, 7000]})

def do_split(df1, df2):
    return [df1[A] * B for A,B in zip(df2.A, df2.B)]

newlist = do_split(df_time, df_area)  
newframe = pd.DataFrame(newlist)    
df1_transposed = newframe.T
```

My goal is to get the column `C` from `df_area` as a second header in my Output Dataframe `df1_transposed`(picture below).

[image]

That means that `BUS_X` should be under `area1`, `BUS_Y` under `area2` and the second `BUS_Y` under the second `area1` as headers.

I tried to expand the function like this:

```py
def do_split(df1, df2):
    return [df1[A] * B for A,B,C in zip(df2.A, df2.B,df2.C)]
```

The code then works without any error but the output is the same as in the picture above.

Comment: I find better solution, answer was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
def do_split(df1, df2):
    return [(df1[A] * B).rename((A, C)) for A,B,C in zip(df2.A, df2.B, df2.C)]

df = pd.concat(do_split(df_time, df_area), axis=1)
print (df)
  area1  area2  area1
  BUS_X  BUS_Y  BUS_Y
0  2000  10000   7000
1  4000  25000  14000
2  6000  30000  21000
3  8000  35000  28000
```

Better/faster solution is:

```
df = df_time.mul(df_area.set_index(['A','C'])['B'], level=0)
print (df)
A area1  area2  area1
C BUS_X  BUS_Y  BUS_Y
0  2000  10000   7000
1  4000  25000  14000
2  6000  30000  21000
3  8000  35000  28000
```